# Syntax error in server not on localhost

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have this link:

```
   <a href="{{url('/list')}}">List of all members</a>
```

and this route:

```
Route::get('/list', 'NyfnController@list');
```

controller method:

```
public function list()
    {
        $users=User::orderBy('district_involved')->get();
        return view('list')->with('users',$users);
    }
```

But, i got the syntax error:

> syntax error, unexpected 'list' (T_LIST), expecting identifier
>   (T_STRING)

**This works fine on localhost, but not on server.**

Comment: Does the error message specify which file the syntax error is in?

Comment: @RossWilson yes in this exact method in controller.

Comment: Do you mean you get this error ONLY in the production server and not in your local environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your localhost is running 5.6.4> and your webserver is running 7.*.

In php 7 the list method is not available. If you use PHPStorm you got a notice that `list` is a new method in PHP 7 (or newer). Have a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php#refsect1-function.list-changelog

I would recommend you to change you method:

```
public function listUsers()
{
    $users=User::orderBy('district_involved')->get();
    return view('list')->with('users',$users);
}

Route::get('/list', 'NyfnController@listUsers');
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens that `list` is a reserved word (http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php), actually a language construct, and therefore you cannot define a function with that name. Use whatever other (not reserved) name you want.